# Is it possible for a method of a class to be invoked first before the init constructor?

Tags: python

My class:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        ...

    def get_query_set(self):
        ...
```

I added logs in both `__init__` and `get_query_set` and I have noticed that the log output in the latter gets printed out (but none for the one in `__init__`. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__init__` function can call arbitrary methods itself, and construction of objects in Python can also be complicated with [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), so make sure both outputs refer to the same object (for example, by including `id(self)` in the output).

To find out who called `get_query_set`, you can use [`traceback.print_stack`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack):

```
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: They were different instances (different id(self)). I know how to debug this now. Thanks.